# Using a loop to display how many cubes can fit into a box?

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the assignment i have: For sake of ease, they only want to know how many whole cubes we can fit into each box. Also, assume each cube fits neatly into the box; we don't have to handle partially allocated rows. (The instructor will explain this in class.)

Our assignment is to modify the first volume calculator to display the extra result of how many cubes will fit into the box. This assignment will require the use of loops and methods. While the professor knows this calculator can be coded without using any loops, one point of this assignment is to help understand looping constructs. The form's UI won't change in that we still have to accept length, width, and height.

Additionally, this assignment must provide exception handling. Do not assume the user is going to type only valid numbers! (Hint, one of the users won't.) Finally, have a MessageBox display the result in the form: A box with length l, width w, and depth d has a volume of x, and can hold n cubes.

I cannot figure out how to calculate this through a loop. This is what i have so far.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Project_2
{
    public partial class VolumeCalculator : Form
    {
        public VolumeCalculator()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Length.TextChanged += OnTextBoxTextChanged;
            Width.TextChanged += OnTextBoxTextChanged;
            Depth.TextChanged += OnTextBoxTextChanged;

            Length.KeyPress += OnTextBoxKeyPress;
            Width.KeyPress += OnTextBoxKeyPress;
            Depth.KeyPress += OnTextBoxKeyPress;

            Calculate.Click += OnCalculateClick;
        }

        void OnTextBoxKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter && Calculate.Enabled)
            {
                OnCalculateClick(this, new EventArgs());
            }
        }

        void OnCalculateClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            double width;
            double length;
            double depth;
            double volume;

            if (!double.TryParse(Length.Text, out length))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid length entered.", "Volume Calculator",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                Length.Focus();
                Length.SelectAll();
            }
            else if (!double.TryParse(Width.Text, out width))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid width entered.", "Volume Calculator",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                Width.Focus();
                Width.SelectAll();
            }
            else if (!double.TryParse(Depth.Text, out depth))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid depth entered.", "Volume Calculator",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                Depth.Focus();
                Depth.SelectAll();
            }
            else
            {
                volume = length * width * depth;
                MessageBox.Show(string.Format("A box with length {0:0.0}, width {1:0.0}, and depth {2:0.0} has a volume of {3:0.00}.",
                    length, width, depth, volume));
            }
        }

        void OnTextBoxTextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Calculate.Enabled = Length.Text.Trim().Length > 0 &&
                                Width.Text.Trim().Length > 0 &&
                                Depth.Text.Trim().Length > 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Shouldn't the user enter the size of the cube somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Don't computer science teachers um... use computers on the internet? Perhaps even use StackOverflow?

Checking for invalid input is good. After you give an error message and do the .SelectAll, use

```
return;
```

to leave the OnCalculateClick function. In almost every case, you enter a function, validate the input values, if they are unusable, report and exit the function.

The only place I see a loop would be to replace

```
volume = length * width * depth;
```

with:

```
int volume = 0;
for (int l = 0; l < length; l++)
{
    // etc... for the student to figure out
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a method for the conversion and validation

```
bool TryConvert(TextBox textBox, out double value)
{
    if (!Double.TryPare(textBox.Text, out value)) {
        string message = String.Format("Invalid {0} entered.", textBox.Name.ToLower());
        MessageBox.Show(message , "Volume Calculator", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                        MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        textBox.Focus();
        textBox.SelectAll();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now, `OnCalculateClick` becomes easier:

```
void OnCalculateClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double width;
    double length;
    double depth;
    double volume;

    if (TryConvert(Length, out length) &&
        TryConvert(Width, out width) &&
        TryConvert(Depth, out depth))
    {
        volume = length * width * depth;
        string message = String.Format(
            "A box with length {0:0.0}, width {1:0.0}, and depth {2:0.0} has a volume of {3:0.00}.",
            length, width, depth, volume); 
        MessageBox.Show(message);
    }
}
```

---

You could use a loop in order to find how many times the cube fits into a box dimension. I explain it in words: set an counter to 0. Repeat a loop while counter times cube size is less than or equal to one of the box dimensions. Increase the counter by one at each loop. Do this for all 3 dimensions and multiply the three counts.

And of course, put this calculation into another method. Then you can call it three times with different parameters 3 times.